# Excel - reference another worksheet by a string in a random cell, and reference a value in its given row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to reference a string in another worksheet in a random cell, and reference a value in its given row.

The reason is that I'm working with 30+ documents, and the given string (and the value that I need next to it) Appears at different positions in each document.

I need to collect these values from each document, and combine it into one.

Thanks!

Comment: Having a little trouble understanding, can you expand your question with a very simple example?

Comment: Do you really mean a *random* cell, or do you mean an *unknown* cell? If the latter, there might be a solution involving `VLookup`, but your question is so obscure it is hard to say.

Comment: Sounds **possibly** like a job for `INDIRECT`.  (Getting a single value from a random location would be easy using INDIRECT, but also doing something with the cell next to it may be harder unless you are happy to store the value of the random number defining the row somewhere first.)

Answer (score 2):

Say on *Sheet6* there is some cell that contains the phrase:

```
happiness is
```

and we want to retrieve the contents of the cell just to the right of it:

[image]

First enter the following *UDF* in a standard module:

```
Public Function Find_Range(Find_Item As Variant, _
    Search_Range As Range, _
    Optional LookIn As Variant, _
    Optional LookAt As Variant, _
    Optional MatchCase As Boolean) As String

    Dim c As Range
    If IsMissing(LookIn) Then LookIn = xlValues 'xlFormulas
    If IsMissing(LookAt) Then LookAt = xlPart 'xlWhole
    If IsMissing(MatchCase) Then MatchCase = False
    With Search_Range
        Set c = .Find( _
        What:=Find_Item, _
        LookIn:=LookIn, _
        LookAt:=LookAt, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=MatchCase, _
        SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
             Find_Range = Search_Range.Parent.Name & "!" & c.Address
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

The *UDF* will search for `Find_Item` and return the address as a string.  So:

```
=find_range("happiness is",Sheet6!1:1048576)
```

will return:

```
Sheet6!$E$13
```

Note that the search range is the **entire** *Sheet6*.  But we want an *OFFSET()*, so pick some cell in *Sheet5* and enter:

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(find_range("happiness is",Sheet6!1:1048576)),0,1)
```

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=Find_Range(A1,C1:X100)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Nice answer (so +1) though I am not sure that it is a good use of time to do so much work in answering such an unclear question.

Comment: @JohnColeman  You are probably right...I already had the *UDF()*, so for me, the fun part was figuring out how to combine *OFFSET()* with *INDIRECT()*

Comment: Seems like reason enough. Besides, you aren't just writing for OP. Even if it turns out to not help them, it might help other people in the future who are searching for some method to look up information on another sheet.

Comment: @JohnColeman perhaps....but this is only a Student's solution...maybe some clever person can do it without VBA.